# OpenVPN routing

Tags: networking, openvpn

My VPN network is 10.10.10.0

Apart from the server I have two special machines.
I need all the clients to see 10.10.10.10 and I also need 10.10.10.30 to see all the clients.

Enabling client-to-client in server configuration causes a small mess because then all 10.10.10.0 traffic is routed through the VPN server (e.g 10.10.10.200 could be a machine local to the client)

Any idea how to handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different networks so that the VPN network is very unlikely to match a local network that is being used.

For example, 172.16/12 prefix is seldom used anywhere, so you could change your VPN to use some subnet from that range, and then you wouldn't encounter this problem.

Comment: It was set on purpose 10.10.10.0 on client and server side so that all connected clients could see 10.10.10.10 from wherever they connect. If I use 172.16/12 network how would this be possible?

Comment: You need to add routes to the 10.10.10.0/24 network, so that all requests to that network are routed via VPN. For example `push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"` in OpenVPN server configuration.

Comment: I am already doing that. 10.10.10.1 is the server 10.10.10.50 connects from the client site. Everything works just fine with client-to-client until 10.10.10.50 wants to communicate with 10.10.10.51 which is also at the client site! Then all traffic is lost through the gateway (10.10.10.1).

Comment: You need to change the OpenVPN network to something else than 10.10.10.0/24, like something in 172.16/12 range, and then push the routes via the OpenVPN network.

Comment: Tested this, network-wise it was fine, but still I had some technical issues (IPs hardwired in applications etc). So I took the hard way, manually configured the remote networks with static IPs. Used ccd on OpenVPN to avoid troublesome IPs. For those 2 special addresses .10 and .30 I had to keep client-to-client open and setup a firewall to get the behavior I wanted. Cheers!